# Objects not showing in viewport on Solid view

Tags: 3d-view, transparency, object-mode

Greetings fellow blenders.

I got tired of looking around for a fix and writing here is my last resource. I updated Blender from 2.80 to 2.81, and surprise: All objects in the viewport are displaying transparent in both eevee or Cycles. I am able to select them, and the outline of them shows up (see images for reference). Here is the strange thing, even the start up document (the general default with the cube) opens messed up.

That is in object mode. Whenever I change to edit mode, the object appears and shows correctly (see image)...

I was thinking maybe it was related to the fact Blender 2.81 might no longer support my video card, but how come it shows using edit mode?

Am I missing something here?

Images for reference:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your GPU drivers? If not, try doing it. I can't think of anything else than old drivers. If that doesn't help you - you can try installing blender again. If that doesn't help too, go and report it [here](https://developer.blender.org/). It can be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Going to report it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when at objects with two materials attached to different faces, those faces got invisible in solid mode, while being selectable and showing up in rendered(Cycles) mode. Only in 2.81, not in 2.80. Solution: new graphics card capable of OpenGL >3.3.

Another problem occurred simultaneously, but with different reason: some objects shaded completely transparent, making other objects behind them also transparent. This could be solved only by re-modelling the objects and creating a new material.