# Objects are invisible

Tags: modeling

Objects are invisible in Object/Sculpt mode, but not in the Edit mode - mesh is still here.
I have been using Blender before, but this glitch only appeared now
Thanks in advance
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For **Viewport Shading** you have both **X-ray**(orange in the image below) and **Wire frame** (red) enabled.
Enabling the **Solid** mode (green) Viewport Shading option instead should fix it.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the same situation goes even with the solid mode, but thanks for answer
https://sun9-39.userapi.com/impf/K2s7iJDE40SfImrKwtatCRp5Vu7Hgcy3tV3dZQ/d34Xvg6P59U.jpg?size=946x788&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=7e6bc833b395d24c66d4b3c4a3ec15fc

Comment: What happens if you copy and paste a couple of the objects into a new blender Blender file? Can you share your file (or a file with a couple of the objects ) using this  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to paste it into your original question?

Comment: perhaps this  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159638/objects-not-showing-in-viewport-on-solid-view